Angular grid scroll event is not calling during scroll
There is a angular grid with scrollbar and on scroll we need to call the scroll event (lazy loading).
<div class="table-container" [ngClass]="{'loading': isLoading}" style="max-height: 400px; overflow-y: auto;"
     infinite-scroll
     [infiniteScrollDistance]="2"
     [infiniteScrollThrottle]="150"
     (scrolled)="onScroll($event)">
  <table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort cdk-table class="nest-table">
  </table>
</div>

but onScroll event is not getting triggered during grid scrollbar scrolling. Please have a look and suggest.

scrolled is not a native event, I suppose it is provided by the infinite-scroll directive. Where does this directive come from? I have never seen this in Angular or Angular Material.

(scroll)="onScroll()" try using scroll event in angular

@JSONDerulo i am using ngx-infinite-scroll package

@kawai_weebster this is not a good advice here, as the scrolled event is only emitted when the threshold has been reached, while the native scroll event emits on every scroll.

You need to make sure that the scroll bar is on the table-container element and not some other element like the table. By applying a max-width and overflow-y, it looks like that's the case, however from the given code we can't be 100% sure. Without a minimal reproducible example it's hard to help here.

@JSONDerulo the question indicates that he doesn't get the scroll event when scrolling :/ no mention on having the event emitted on a threshold being scrolled to

This is my css
.table-container {
  height: 400px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.outer-container {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

  .nest-table {
  width: 100%;
}

